# How to programatically get video file currently playing in VLC with VB.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, vlc

My first attempt was to get the window title from the process object using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("vlc").MainWindowTitle()
```

This works as long as the file being played does not have the "title" metadata set, if it does the window title is not the filename but whatever was set for the title.

This has to be done on a GUI (client) instance of VLC separate from my application, so the HTTP and other interfaces VLC provides is out of the question, and I believe that also means using libvlc is also out of the question (I don't want to embed VLC in my app).

Is this possible? Does VLC provide no way to interact with it when running in it's normal client mode? Are there any other tricks I'm not thinking of, like finding out through windows a list of files it's accessing or something along those lines? Given a list of files VLC is reading from I could figure out which one is a video file... Anything like this with windows diagnostics or anything similar?

Thank you

Comment: It should be the first entry in the recent media sub menu.

Comment: Okay but how would I get that information from my program? Is there a way to read the menu structure of a different application?

Comment: UI Automation allows to use an InvokePatter to Invoke() the default action of a menu element. The default action of a Menu is to open the menu. If you perform this invocation on the subitems that are created after the invocation, you can get to the sub-menu you're looking for. That's easier said than done, if you don't have experience with UI Automation. Doable, nonetheless.